# git config set executable permissions on certain filetypes

Tags: git, git-config

In windows in my git repo whenever I commit a .sh file, the file permissions are set to `644`, unless I pass the `--chmod=+x` flag to the add command. Is there way to set the permissions as `744` for all .sh filetype in the git config file